# Dynamically load contents of a js file within a function

Tags: javascript, html, django-templates, javascript-objects, plotly.js

I am trying to dynamically load the contents of a .js file (`vis_data1.js`) within another function `getExampleValue`.

In the `getExampleValue` function, I want to include the contents of js/vis_data1.js below the following two lines.

```
// Attach an event listener to the button
 var data_option = document.getElementById('result-select').value;
 console.log(data_option)

// I want to inject the content here by loading "{% static 'js/vis_' %}" + data_option + ".js"
```

I tried to include another function (`loadScript`) within `getExampleValue` to load the script
vis_data1.js.

```
function loadScript(option) {
                        var scriptPath = "{% static 'js/visualization_pressure.js' %}";
                        var scriptElement = document.createElement("script");
                        scriptElement.src = scriptPath;
                        scriptElement.async = true;

                        document.body.appendChild(scriptElement);
                    }
```

But I think the loadscript function included the file contents to the body and not at the line where loadscript is called within the function `getExampleValue`.

Complete code:

```
{% load static %}
<html>
    <head>
        <nav class="nav">
            <ul class="nav__links">
                <li class="nav__item">
                    <a class="nav__link" href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav__item">
                    <a class="nav__link" href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav__item">
                    <a class="nav__link" href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a>
                </li>
                 </ul>
        </nav>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>
            Visualization
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-1.58.5.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            .graph-container {
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
                height: 100vh;
            }
            .main-panel {
                width: 100%;
                height: 800px;
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
            }
            .side-panel {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0px;
                bottom: 0;
                right: -300px;
                width: 300px;
                background-color: red;
                transition: right 0.5s;
                overflow-y: auto;
                padding: 20px;
            }

            .side-panel.open {
                right: 0;
            }

            .arrow {
                position: absolute;
                top: 20px;
                left: 20px;
                width: 0;
                height: 0;
                border-top: 20px solid transparent;
                border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
                border-right: 20px solid #2196F3;
                cursor: pointer;
            }

            .arrow.open {
                transform: rotate(180deg);
            }

            .left-arrow {
                position: absolute;
                top: 20px;
                right: 20px;
                width: 0;
                height: 0;
                border-top: 20px solid transparent;
                border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
                border-right: 20px solid #2196F3;
                cursor: pointer;
            }

            .open .left-arrow {
                transform: rotate(180deg);
            }

            {# Added Code for side bar  #}

            .sidenav {
              height: 100%;
              width: 250px;
              position: fixed;
              z-index: 3;
              top: 80px;
              left: 0px;
              background-color: #111;
              overflow-x: hidden;
              transition: 0.5s;
              padding-top: 60px;
            }

            .open .sidenav {
               left: -20px;
            }

            .sidenav a {
              padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
              text-decoration: none;
              font-size: 25px;
              color: #818181;
              display: block;
              transition: 0.3s;
            }

            .sidenav a:hover {
              color: #f1f1f1;
            }

            .sidenav .closebtn {
              position: absolute;
              top: 0;
              right: 25px;
              font-size: 36px;
              margin-left: 50px;
            }

            #main {
                transition: margin-left .5s;
                padding: 16px;
                margin-left: 250px;
            }

            .form {
                border-radius: 20px;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                height: 500px;
                padding: 20px;
                width: inherit;
                font-size: 1.8rem;
            }

            .title{
                color: #eee;
                font-family: "Bitstream Vera Sans Mono", Monaco, "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
                font-size: 25px;
                font-weight: 400;
                padding-left: 15px;

            }

            .input-container {
                height: 50px;
                position: relative;
                width: 100%;
            }

            .soura {
              margin-top: 40px;
            }

            .ic2 {
              margin-top: 30px;
            }

            .input {
              background-color: #303245;
              border-radius: 12px;
              border: 0;
              box-sizing: border-box;
              color: #eee;
              font-size: 18px;
              height: 100%;
              outline: 0;
              padding: 4px 20px 0;
              width: 100%;
            }

            .cut {
              background-color: black;
              border-radius: 10px;
              height: 20px;
              left: 20px;
              position: absolute;
              top: -20px;
              transform: translateY(0);
              transition: transform 200ms;

            }

            .arrowsize-cut{
                width: 80px;
            }

            .concentration-cut{
                width: 105px;
            }

            .example-cut{
                width: 140px;
            }

            .labelsize-cut{
                width: 80px;
            }

            .input:focus ~ .cut,
            .input:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ .cut {
              transform: translateY(8px);
            }

            .placeholder {
              color: #65657b;
              font-family: sans-serif;
              left: 20px;
              line-height: 14px;
              position: absolute;
              transform-origin: 0 50%;
              transition: transform 200ms, color 200ms;
              top: 20px;
            }

            .input:focus ~ .placeholder,
            .input:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ .placeholder {
              transform: translateY(-30px) translateX(10px) scale(0.75);
            }

            .input:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ .placeholder {
              color: #808097;
            }

            .input:focus ~ .placeholder {
              color: #dc2f55;
            }

            .submit {
              background-color: #08d;
              border-radius: 12px;
              border: 0;
              box-sizing: border-box;
              color: #eee;
              cursor: pointer;
              font-size: 18px;
              height: 30px;
              margin-top: 38px;
              outline: 0;
              text-align: center;
              width: 100%;
            }

            .submit:active {
              background-color: #06b;
            }

            /* Adding the button */

            @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
              .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
              .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
            }

            /* Code for download button */

            .hide {
                max-height: 0 !important;
            }

            .dropdown{
                border: 0.1em solid white;
                width: 18em;
                margin-bottom: 1em;
                margin-top: 2rem;
                position: relative;
            }

            .dropdown .title{
                margin: .3em .3em .3em .3em;
                width: 100%;
            }

            .dropdown .title .fa-angle-right{
                float: right;
                margin-right: .7em;
                transition: transform .3s;
            }

            .dropdown .menu{
                transition: bottom .5s ease-out;
                background-color: black;
                min-width: 18rem;
                /* bottom: 7.9em; */
                border:  solid white;
                overflow: hidden;
                position: absolute;
                font-size: 10px;
            }

            .dropdown .menu .option{
                margin: .1em .1em .1em .1em;
                margin-top: 0.3em;
                color: white;
                font-size: 10px;
            }

            .dropdown .menu .option:hover{
                background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
            }

            .pointerCursor:hover{
                cursor: pointer;
            }

            .rotate-90{
                transform: rotate(-90deg);
            }

            .clickable {
              cursor: pointer;
              text-decoration: underline;
              color: blue;
            }

            .dropdown .download-button {
              position: absolute;
              top: 0;
              right: -60px; /* Adjust the position as needed */
              width: 50px;
              height: 100%;
              background-color: #333;
              border: none;
              border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
              color: white;
              font-size: 16px;
              cursor: pointer;
            }

            .dropdown .download-button i {
              margin-top: 6px;
            }

        </style>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div id = "main" style="margin-left: 7rem;">

            <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
                <div class="left-arrow" onclick="toggleNav()"></div>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
                    <form class="form" id="myForm" action="{% url 'visualization' %}" method="post">
                      {% csrf_token %}
                      <div class = "title">settings</div>
                      <div class="input-container soura">
                      <input id="examples" class="input" name="examples" placeholder=" " onfocusout=getExampleValue() />
                      <div class="cut example-cut"></div>
                      <label for="examples" class="placeholder">
                          Examples
                          <span id="example1" class="example" onclick="setExampleValue('example1')"> #1</span>
                          <span id="example2" class="example" onclick="setExampleValue('example2')"> #2</span>
                      </label>
                      </div>
                      <div class="input-container ic2">
                          <input id="arrowsize" class="input" type="text" placeholder=" " />
                          <div class="cut arrowsize-cut"></div>
                          <label for="arrowsize" class="placeholder">arrow size</label>
                      </div>
                      <div class="input-container ic2">
                          <input id="labelsize" class="input" type="text" placeholder=" " />
                          <div class="cut arrowsize-cut"></div>
                          <label for="labelsize" class="placeholder">label font-size</label>
                      </div>
                      <button type="submit" class="submit">Submit</button>
                    </form>

                <div class='dropdown'>
                    <a class='title pointerCursor'>Download <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                    <div class='menu pointerCursor hide'>
                        <div class='option' id='option1'><a href="#">PNG</a></div>
                        <div class='option' id='option2'><a href="#">SVG</a></div>
                        <div class='option' id='option3'><a href="#">JPEG</a></div>
                    </div>
                    <button class="download-button"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></button>
                </div>
                <div class="center-container">
                        <div class='dropdown'>
                            <label for="result-select"></label>
                            <select id="result-select" class="pointerCursor">
                                <option value="data1">data1</option>
                                <option value="data2">data2</option>
                                <option value="data3">data3</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="graph-container">
                <div id="network" class="main-panel"></div>
                <div id="graph" class="side-panel">
                    <div class="arrow"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/adf1f3a283.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>

            let navState = false;
            function toggleNav() {
              if(navState){
                closeNav();
              }else{
                openNav();
              }
              navState = !navState;
            }

            function openNav() {
                // document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "open";
                document.getElementById("mySidenav").classList.add("open");
                document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
            }

            function closeNav() {
                // document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "open";
                document.getElementById("mySidenav").classList.remove("open");
                document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "50px";
            }

            // examples
            function setExampleValue(value) {
                document.getElementById("examples").value = value;
            }


            // download options
            const dropdownTitle = document.querySelector('.dropdown .title');
            const dropdownMenu = document.querySelector('.dropdown .menu');

            dropdownTitle.addEventListener('click', function () {
                dropdownMenu.classList.toggle('hide');
            });

            document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown .option').forEach(function (option) {
                option.addEventListener('click', function () {
                    // Handle the selected download option here
                    const selectedOption = this.textContent;
                    console.log('Selected option:', selectedOption);

                    // Display the selected option in the dropdown title
                    dropdownTitle.textContent = `Download ${selectedOption}`;

                    // Close the dropdown menu
                    dropdownMenu.classList.add('hide');
                });
            });

            function getExampleValue() {
                const fid = document.getElementById("examples").value;
                console.log(fid)

                const fpath = `${fid}.json`;

                //read the data from the json file
                fetch(fpath)
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(data => {
                        var x = data.x

                    // Attach an event listener to the button
                    var data_option = document.getElementById('result-select').value;
                    console.log(data_option)

                    // I want to inject the content here by loading "{% static 'js/vis_' %}" + data_option + ".js"


                    Plotly.newPlot('network', data, layout);
                    })
            }
        </script>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The file vis_data1.js includes data and layout settings for drawing the plotly graph called within
`getExampleValue`.

Please note: `data_option` is a dynamic variable that will change depending on the dropdown option the user selects in the front end. So the file will be vis_data1.js or  vis_data2.js
.... Accordingly, the plotly graph input will change.

Suggestions on how to include the contents of file vis_data1.js within getExampleValue will be really helpful.

Comment: Why not having the content of these .js files wrapped into specific functions and then bundled into one single file which you load initially within the document ? ie. given `data_option`, instead of having to load the script `\`js/vis_${data_option}.js\`` you would just have to call the wrapper function corresponding to that file content.

Answer (score 4):

If you use this syntax:

```js
var scriptPath = "{% static 'js/visualization_pressure.js' %}";
```

The scriptPath variable will be exactly that text.

The [static template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/) only works on server because it has Django template engine. So, you should write the real path. For example:

```js
function loadScript(option) {
 var scriptElement = document.createElement("script");
 scriptElement.src = "/my-app-context/static-folder/js/visualization_pressure.js";
 scriptElement.async = true;
 document.body.appendChild(scriptElement);
}
```